# spell check : Tiny MCE editor

Tags: ssl, editor, tinymce

i am getting this error while i am enter some text and click on spellcheck icon in tinyMCE Editor..

Error response:

```
Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: 
getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in 
/home/web/rattspar.se/scripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/classes/GoogleSpell.php 
on line 86 Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 
ssl://www.google.com:443 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: 
Temporary failure in name resolution) in 
/home/web/rattspar.se/scripts/tiny_mce/plugins/spellchecker/classes/GoogleSpell.php
on line 86 Could not open SSL connection to google.{"id":null,"result":[],"error":null}
```

help me out/uday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi finally i got the answer. we have to Un-comment the line extension=php_curl.dll and extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini and then restart the server.;-)